# How to set bootstrap checkbox to true from javascript/typescript code?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have set a checkbox list using the following code:

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="0" (change)="getSelectedCheckbox($event)" (checked)="getCheckedSites()"  >
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
      {{sites[0]}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="1" (change)="getSelectedCheckbox($event)">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    {{sites[1]}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="2" (change)="getSelectedCheckbox($event)">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    {{sites[2]}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="3" (change)="getSelectedCheckbox($event)">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    {{sites[3]}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="4" (change)="getSelectedCheckbox($event)">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    {{sites[4]}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="5" (change)="getSelectedCheckbox($event)">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    {{sites[5]}}
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to set the state of a checkbox(whether checked or not) from the javascript/typescript file.
I am using Angular so I tried the following in the html file:

```html
(checked)="getCheckedSites()
```

And in the typescript file, I wrote this method:

```js
getCheckedSites(){
  return true
}
```

Obviously, it didn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Angular, you have two ways of doing this:

1: You can use the `[checked]` property, which receives a boolean value saying if the input is checked or not. This is only if you need one-way data binding.

2: You can use the `[(ngModel)]`. As it is an input, you can still assign a value using `ngModel`. But, in this case, this is two-way data binding and will change the value in your model if the user checks/unchecks the checkbox.

I created a demo in Stackblitz, so you can both ways better (open the browser console to see what's happening in the model): https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-input-demonstration

You can take a better look in two-way data binding in this post: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get whether you want to check a checkbox,or see if it's checked, so i will give you 2 answers depending on what you want,using javascript:

1. if you want to see if a checkbox is checked or not, you may use:

   `var check = document.getElementById("ID").checked;` check = false if your element is unchecked,otherwise check = true;
2. if you want to force check a checkbox you may use:
    `document.getElementById("ID").checked = true;`

PS: this solution you aim at a speceic checkbox using its ID, if you want to check all your checkboxes you better use the following code:

```
 var checkList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"); 
    for(var i = 0;i < checkList.length;i++){
       // your operation here
   }
```